# How do I return 2 values for this method?

Tags: c#

This is my current code:

```
public static double CalculateTip(double totalExpense)
{
    const double TIP1 = 0.15;

    return totalExpense * TIP1;
}

//Calculation for tip 2 
public static double CalculateTip2(double totalExpense)
{
    const double TIP2 = 0.20;

    return totalExpense * TIP2;

}
```

How can I possibly combine the 2 into 1 method?  My program runs perfect and according to instruction by the professor, but I used 5 methods instead of 4. Apparently you must be able to combine the two, otherwise he wouldn't say he only wants 4 methods in his instructions.

final output of the program looks like this

```
                      Tip Calculator
Please enter the total:

Clear console

                      Tip Calculator
The total before taxes and tip: 50.00 (user input obviously)
Taxes : $4.50
Tip 15%: $7.50
Total including taxes and 15% tip: $62.00
Tip 20%: 10:00
Total including taxes and 20% tip: $64.50
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider using [Tuple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Tuple<double, double> CalculateTip(double totalExpense)
{
    const double TIP1 = 0.15;
    const double TIP2 = 0.20;
    return Tuple.Create<double, double>(totalExpense * TIP1, totalExpense * TIP2);
}
```

Comment: Or if you want to make ot look like you figured it out yourself, use 2 out parameters on one method. Great answer though, @AlexD.

Answer (score 2):

Anytime that you have two methods that are identical except for some constant, you should think about making that a parameter to the method.

The method should do one thing, calculate the tip amount (not calculate two tip amounts).

Consider passing the tip percentage into the method and calling it twice.

Also, don't use doubles for currency, you should use `Decimal` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the Tip as an additional parameter to a (common) CalculateTip() function (so the function will have two parameters, tip and totalExpense) and call it twice, with different Tip values. It is the same function indeed - just operating on different parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the *method take in the tip percent* instead of having constant values within the method.  Keep the constant's at the class level and use them in the method call.  This makes it more dynamic, and able to be combined.

```
readonly double TIP1 = 0.15;
readonly double TIP2 = 0.20;

public static double CalculateTip(double totalExpense, double tip)
{
    return totalExpense * tip;
}
```

Then when calling the method you can specify what tip value you want to use:

```
var tip1Value = CalculateTip(20.00,TIP1);
var tip2Value = CalculateTip(20.00,TIP2);
```